# Is it compulsory to make preflight request before each CORS request?

Tags: optimization, cors, cdn, akamai

Today when i was watching IPL match on JioCinemas, I have opened network tab just to see what all requests it making, response time, cdn provider etc
I have noticed that JioCinemas is making Preflight request before each Get request to CDN. I was wondering why is JioCinemas making preflight request everytime. Cant we cache it for say 1 minute/ 30 secs. As per my understanding the whole purpose of preflight request is to find out if a cross origin request can be made or not ? Am i missing anything here ?

Attaching image of my network tab for Reference
[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReU97.png)

Comment: The browser decides when it sends a preflight request, not the website

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid CORS by putting you content on the same domain. It may be easier to do with a CDN in front of your servers.

If separated domains are required, then you may offload CORS to the CDN to make it as fast as possible and avoid using resources on your Origin servers.